# How to get the area?

Tags: geometry

I have this statement:

If $E,H,G,F$ are midpoints and $AB = 12, BC =5$, What is the value of the shadow area ?

[image]

My attempt was:

Both shadow triangles are congruent. $EBGD$ is a parallelogram its area is equal to $30 = 2\cdot A_x +A _2$, where $A_x$ is the area of each shadow triangle and $A_2$ is the parallelogram $DKBT$

Also, $\triangle DTH \cong \triangle KFB$, and its area are equal. Let $A_3$ the area of each of these triangles. Also i can get that $A_3 = A_x$

The sum of the total area is equal to $4A_x+A_2 + 2A_4=60$, where $A_4$ is equal to the area of quadrilateral $AFKE \cong TGCH$, but from here i can't get more. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: In triangle $ABD$ medians $BE$ and $DF$ cut each other in the ratio $1:2$.

Comment: Thanks Aretino, solved.

Answer (score 1):

Under linear transform, the ratio of areas of different regions remain invariant.

If one apply a linear transform to $\triangle BCD$ and map it to an equilateral triangle. One find the image of $\triangle BCD$ is congruent to $6$ copies of image of $\triangle BGT$. This implies
$$\verb/Area/(BGT) = \frac16 \verb/Area/(BCD)$$
By a similar argument,
$$\verb/Area/(EKD) = \frac16 \verb/Area/(ABD)$$

As a result, the area of the shaded region is $\frac16(12)(5) = 10$.